# Node.JS module error - Is not a function when calling it from my index.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to make use of a newly create Node.JS module but I am getting an error saying: `"Is not a function"`.

**lib/weather.mjs**

```
My module's code is below:
// Gets the weather of a given location
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

var latLongAirports = [{
        "name": "Madrid",
        "iata": "MAD",
        "lat": 40.49565434242003,
        "long": -3.574541319609411,
    },{
        "name": "Los Angeles",
        "iata": "LAX",
        "lat": 33.93771087455066,
        "long": -118.4007447751959,
    },{
        "name": "Mexico City",
        "iata": "MEX",
        "lat": 19.437281814699613,
        "long": -99.06588831304731,}]

export default function getTemperature (iata){
    async (dispatch) =>{
        let data = latLongAirports.find(el => el.iata === iata);
        var url = "http://www.7timer.info/bin/api.pl?lon=" + data.long + "&lat=" + data.lat + "&product=astro&output=json"
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const myJson = await response.json();
        return myJson.dataseries[0].temp2m
    }
}
```

And this is how I am trying to use it from my **main.js**

```
import weather from './lib/weather.mjs'
var temperature = weather.getTemperature("MEX")
```

What am I doing wrong here?
How should I declare and use self written modules like those?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the value of `type` in your `package.json` file?

Comment: "type": "module",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`weather.mjs` is exporting the function. So what you get in `main.js` is the actual function.

In your `main.js` you should call the exported method like

```js
import getTemperature from './lib/weather.mjs'
var temperature = getTemperature("MEX")
```